# Login logout session in VB.net without asp.net

Tags: vb.net, session

Is there a way to handle login and logout session of standalone vb.net application?
I have an application with a DB data. Users can access this data using application API's.

I already have login and logout functions defined for the users, but they have to login every time they open application, which is safe way, but in a local intranet environment its not necessary to do it every time.

I was wondering if i could store some kind of session id on a local PC where this application is running and then crosscheck if its still valid and not request users to fill in the login details.

But storing key to access the data is not secure. So how would i go about to make it secure and user friendly?

Is there a resource on how to handle the sessions?

```
My goal is:
1)Open app
2)Login to your account and access data
3)Do stuff ya need
4)Close app.
```

Few moments later..

Open app and you still logged in and can do stuff.

Few days later...

Open app and it asks to login.

---

Im thinking of doing something like this:

```
On login:
Check if session is expired
If expired = true
Set sessionID 
Save sessionID in registry
Save UserID in registry
Set endOfLifeDate
```

Problem with this, someone could snoop the registry and get them sessionID and userID and get acces to the DATA.

Then next thought is:

```
On login: 
Check if session is expired 
If expired = true 
Get CurrentNetworkPCname 
Hash the userid and sessionID and CurrentNetworkPCname 
Save sessionID in registry 
Save UserID in registry 
Set endOfLifeDate
```

this way you will need to be on the same pc to access the DATA.

Im open to ideas, im no expert as you can see.

Comment: Isn’t this exactly what session cookies do?

Comment: @Hursey sorry for late reply. The idea here is not to use http stuff. Im building standalone app. Not sure how to use only the cookie portion for my app tho.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you want an asp app for this, the way I’m reading this I’m wondering if maybe what you’ve really after is something more along the lines of a winforms app.

Comment: @Hursey the title said WITHOUT asp.net :D. Yeah im making along the winform lines/wpf type app that is why.

Comment: Well what does cookies have to do with it at all then.  Cookies are really a web app thing,  you can mimic some of the functionality of cookies I guess but it’s not really something to worry about in a winforms space

Comment: @Hursey well maybe you didnt read my question that well. Im looking for a way to mimic cookies in wpf app, withouth writing boilerplate code. Maybe there are some solutions already integrated in the .net that i dont know about. That is why im asking. The key is to make it safe for users to access DATA. Im noob in these things not sure where to start.

Comment: Yeah I will admit I probably didn’t re-read your question since originally posted, mixing terminology certainly didn’t help.  Anyway, there a heap of different ways you could look at, really it’s up to you to do the research and decide what works best for you.  You can save things to the window registry although that may give you problems re UAT or you can store settings in files in the user profile, commonly done with serialised json/XML.

Comment: Sorry if that sounds a little unhelpful, but really it’s the best you’re likely to get here.  This site is really more for solving issues rather than designing solutions

Comment: @Hursey its helpful, any comments are better than no comments. I just thought maybe there are better ways to store that key info than in plain registries or files, but i guess its not. Anyway thanks for the ideas. i might update the post when i come to a solution.

Comment: If user profile settings files aren't your thing, could go with a db.  You could look at using Active Directory for authentication.  There a ton of options

Comment: i have no problem with profile file or db. How do you think users could access db? using a password or some type of secret. I dont want users to enter it every time they open the app.. i know its safer but its just too much to ask from lazy bums. I was wondering how could i keep that secret stored somewhere when the app is opened it  checks the secret and if its valid then it lets you in. Storing password on a desktop is not safe :D. I was thinking how can i generate secret that is only valid on current machine and if you enter the secret from another machine its not valid.

Comment: Well,  again it really depends on your exact requirements.  Say using MSSQL, you could use Integrated Security which means the DB login would be built into the windows user.  You could build some authentication webservice that implemtents (or mimics) and OAuth2 process or you could store the password in encrypted strings.  Choice is yours.  Although I would say, if the users isn't entering passwords what is really the point, and you can guarantee when they forget the password because they never enter it, it will be your fault and responsibility to sort it